# MySQLi finds two rows when there's only one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have some PHP code,

```
$gQ = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Inventory` WHERE `UserID`='$user[ID]' ORDER BY `ID`");
$gN = $gQ->num_rows;
echo($gN);
```

My $user[ID] is 1, so it should fetch anything in Inventory that is owned by UserID 1.
When I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Inventory` WHERE `UserID`='1' ORDER BY `ID`
```

In PhpMyAdmin, it returns 1 row (because there is only 1 row!)

Whereas on the page it returns the number 2.
Why is this? I want it to echo 1 rather than 2.

Comment: did you try to fetch the records?

Comment: Make sure the query that's being executed is exactly what you expect. Add a print statement before you execute the query, ie: (`echo "SELECT * FROM \`Inventory\` WHERE \`UserID\`='$user[ID]' ORDER BY \`ID\`";`)

Comment: What results do you get if you used `SELECT UserID FROM` etc. instead of `*` ?

Comment: Another thing you could do is just to print the rows returned by MySQLi. Then you'll find out the query probably wasn't what you had in mind.

Comment: This is the phpmyadmin result: http://prntscr.com/210gfe - as you can see there is only 1 UserID with the value 1.

Comment: Try to fetch the result, if there are 2 rows, then let it tell you which are these 2 rows, what do they contain ?

Comment: It's probably the result of your `ORDER BY ID` producing this. What happens if you tried `ORDER BY UserID`?

Comment: Using $gQ = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Inventory` WHERE `UserID`='$user[ID]' ORDER BY `ID`");
$gN = $gQ->fetch_array();
echo($gN['ID']); - it returns '1', yet there is no item in the inventory table that holds the ID '1'..

Comment: @Fred-ii- That doesn't change anything

Comment: @EthanWebster Ok. The other possibility I thought of was, that it was probably counting the number of records under `ItemId` which is `12`. It seems like you found the problem, what was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MySQLi finds two rows when there's only one?

No.
Mysqli finds exactly the number of rows found. Whatever inconsistencies and mistakes are caused by your code and/or various typos.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table userID is set to auto_increment, this will assure no duplicate userids (which you obviously have if SQL is bringing 2) use PHP MyAdmin if you can to look at all table records. If the rows are coming out the same double check how you are echoing out your data (would be duplicate code)

Comment: I think having multiple rows with the same `UserID` is something the OP expects to be normal. This is strongly implied with by the `ORDER BY` statement in the query. He just thinks for this particular UserID there should be only one row (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: UserID should not be auto_increment because the same person might have more than one item in their inventory. ID is already set to auto_increment.